# Struts2 url rewriting to populate data to next page via Actionsupport Page

Tags: struts2

Little confused in Struts2

1)Page A displays Iteration data - say 20 unique Records

2)Need to call a new Page B from Page A with Selection of any 1 data

3)Data passed from Page A has to be preprocessed from DB with additional specific 
  Data and the same need to be displayed on Page B

ex --

1) Page A

```
<s:iterator value="SRCHARRDTA" var="itms">    
<tr>
<td nowrap width="20%"><s:property value="%{#itms.FileName}" /></td>
<td nowrap width="20%"><s:property value="%{#itms.FileCategory}" /></td>
<s:hidden name='FILECONTENT'  value='%{#itms.FileName}' /> 
</iterator>
<td nowrap width="10%">
<a href="<s:url  namespace='/SrchData' action='Src5'/>" >
<s:label cssClass='labelsdef' key='label.srchtype2' /></a>
</td>
</tr>
```

2) Retrieve the specific value via  'FILECONTENT' to Struts2 based 
   "abcd extends ActionSupport" class

```
Fetch the Data as per 'FILECONTENT' from DB
Set the Bean values in same calss
```

3) Page B
   Iterate the beans and display same on Page B

How can **1,2,3**  this be done ???

Need a small sample Code ..... please

Skip this process of DB retrival data [ i already know this part ]

with regards
karthik

Comment: Are you asking about this :
`<s:url  namespace='/SrchData' action='Src5' id="myurl">
    <s:param name="param1" value="itms.fileId"/>
</s:url>
<s:a href=%{myurl}>Click To Expand</s:a>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems quite straight forward.
All we need to define an action with one property which will capture the value of file content being sent from page A along with an iterator which contain the values being fetched from the DB.

```
public class FileContentAction extends ActionSupport{

private String FILECONTENT;
// getters and setters

private List<YourBean> beanList;
// getters and setters for this

public String execute() throws Exception{
   Fetch the Data as per 'FILECONTENT' from DB
   Set the Bean values in same calss
   return SUCCESS;
}

}
```

now you need to define the result in your config file.

```
<action name="filecontent" class="com.demo.FileContentAction">
  <result>/pageb.jsp</result>
</action>
```

and in b.jsp

```
<s:iterator value="beanList" var="list"> 
   // since your bean will be top of value stack
   // do what ever you want to display
</s:iterator>
```